# My code works fine from constructor but always returns 1 using a setter

Tags: java, constructor, return, setter

My Java teacher asked for an exponentiation exercise. He wants us to use bucle (for or while) for this, not math functions. Well, I have wrote the code but I realised that if I use the constructor, it works fine. But if I try to choose the value from a setter it always return 1.

```
package potencia;

public class potencia {
    
    private int base = 0;
    private int exponente = 0;
    private int resultado = 1;
    
    public int getBase() {
        return base;
    }

    public int getExponente() {
        return exponente;
    }

    public int getResultado() { // De la variable resultado solo creamos el getter pues no nos interesa "settear" el resultado, sino que lo calcule el programa
        return resultado;
    }

    public void setBase(int base) {
        this.base = base;
    }

    public void setExponente(int exponente) {
        this.exponente = exponente;
    }
        
    public potencia(){}
    
    public potencia(int base, int exponente){
        this.base = base;
        this.exponente = exponente;
            if (exponente == 0) {       // Si la variable EXPONENTE se inicializa a 0, la variable RESULTADO será 1
                this.resultado = 1;
            }
            if (base == 1) {            // Si la variable BASE se inicializa a 1, la variable RESULTADO será 1
                this.resultado = 1;
            }
            if (base > 1 && exponente > 0) {
                for (int i=1; i<=exponente; i++) {
                resultado *= base;  // Uso de operador de asignación "*=", significa lo mismo que "resultado = resultado * base"
                }
            }
    }
    public void muestraResultado () {
        System.out.println("El resultado es " + resultado);
    }  
}
```

The next example works perfectly:

```
package potencia;

public class calcularPotencia {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {

       
        potencia MiCalculadora = new potencia(5, 4);

            MiCalculadora.muestraResultado();
            System.out.println(MiCalculadora.getResultado());
        
    }
    
}
```

It returns: "El resultado es 625
625"

But when I use setters:

```
package potencia;

public class calcularPotencia {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       
        potencia MiCalculadora = new potencia();
            MiCalculadora.setBase(5);
            MiCalculadora.setExponente(4);
            MiCalculadora.muestraResultado();
            System.out.println(MiCalculadora.getResultado());
 
    }
    
}
```

Returns: "El resultado es 1
1"

I supposed that something went wrong with setters and getters, so I deleted them and inserted them again. It was resultless, the fail persists. I also have checked methods and classes, but I can not see the mistake.

Thank you all for your help, mates.

Comment: Resultado should either be always recalculated on each setBase and setExponente call, or only calculated when getResultado is actually called

Comment: Please follow wJava coding conventions.  You have them almost backwards here in terms of your capitalization of the class name and an instance of it.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't calculating the result when you use the setter.
You could remove the member variable for `resultado` and calculate it in the getter:

```
   public int getResultado() { // De la variable resultado solo creamos el getter pues no nos interesa "settear" el resultado, sino que lo calcule el programa
            if (exponente == 0) {       // Si la variable EXPONENTE se inicializa a 0, la variable RESULTADO será 1
                return 1;
            }
            if (base == 1) {            // Si la variable BASE se inicializa a 1, la variable RESULTADO será 1
                return = 1;
            }
            if (base > 1 && exponente > 0) {
                int resultado = 1;
                for (int i=1; i<=exponente; i++) {
                resultado *= base;  // Uso de operador de asignación "*=", significa lo mismo que "resultado = resultado * base"
                }
                return resultado;
            } else {
                throw new RuntimeException("base or exponente < 0");
            }
    }
```

You could also keep the field and cache the result after calculating it.  initialize it to -1, since that is not a valid result. Then do:

```
   public int getResultado() {
        if (resultado < 0) {
           calculateResultado();
        }
        return resultado;
    }
```

Where the calculate method will be similar to what you are doing in the constructor (in fact you can call it from the constructor).

Comment: Thank you for your help. I am not sure what I am doing wrong, but it does not work. Instead of a result it returns an error.

Comment: What error? What is your latest code?